# SQL Server Named Instance TCPIP port settings & EndPoints/Infrastructure permissions error

Tags: sql-server, tcp

I have a local installed SQL Server 2016 (Developer edition) installation on Windows 10 Pro. There is one named instance. I am a developer using MS SQL Management Studio and JetBrains DataGrip.

I just want my connections within my local machine to work with SQL Server over TCPIP using a SQL Server user account..! At the moment this only works using my Windows Authentication mapped to ServerAdmin

Named instance

RAXLENOVOT560\MSSQL2016MAIN
(authentication is mixed mode)

There are 3 issues that maybe linked:

1. TCP Port number does not appear to take effect within the Sql Server Configuration Manager.
2. The Sql Server Configuration Manager only shows limited properties on the Client Protocols/TCPIP settings. (please see screen shots)
3. Sql Server login user account does not connect via TCP due to an error. Login within local machine, local development from DataGrip to SQL Server.

## 1. TCP Port number

I have set this to 65321. However when I try and connect using this port no connection is made.

When I checked using the following SQL query I see the port number is actually 65514

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    local_tcp_port 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
WHERE local_tcp_port IS NOT NULL
```

results

```
local_tcp_port
--------------
65514
```

I change the port number in the config tool, restart ALL SQL Server services, reboot and still nothing works. Still listening on port 65514
Note I did not choose 65514, this seems to be a default from SQL Server.

## 2. The Sql Server Configuration Manager Properties Missing

Note the properties screen is limited only to a few options, there are usually lots more why is is?  Perhaps due to running on Windows 10 Pro vs Windows Server?

[image]

[image]

[image]

## 3. Connection Login failure

Login from the local machine only.

I have opened the firewall for all the relevant SQL Server ports

- TCP 1433
- TCP 65514 (the forced sql server port)
- TCP 65123 (what I would like to use)
- UDP 1434 Sql Server Browser

I attempted login via a number of means

- Sql Server Management Studio
- Udl File
- Java connection via DataGrip

Since opening the firewall, all the connections work but only if the hostname is 127.0.0.1, why can't I use the computer name? The connections also work if I use my Windows Login but NOT a SQL Server login

The login fails due to the error shown below from the SQL Server Log (which proves the TCPIP connection is reaching SQL Server).

```
Login-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Login lacks connect endpoint permission
Date        24/04/2018 11:25:05
Log     SQL Server (Current - 24/04/2018 11:20:00)

Source      Logon

Message
Login failed for user 'SvrDeveloper'. Reason: Login-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Login lacks      connect endpoint permission. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]
```

The Sql Server User has the following permissions and settings (please see screenshot)

- Name = SvrDeveloper
- Server Roles = public
- Securables = RAXLENOVOT560\MSSQL2016MAIN Type=Server
- Securables = TSQL Default TCP Type=EndPoint

Connections

Udl Connection

```
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;User ID="SvrAdmin";Password="Password123";Initial     Catalog="";Data Source=TCP:127.0.01\MSSQL2016MAIN,65514;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial File Name="";Server SPN=""
```

Java connection:
jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:65514;databaseName=CcTools;user=SvrDeveloper;    password=Password123

## Some additional information:

[image]
[image]

Version

Comment: You are only seeing 32-bit properties, but SQL Server 2016 only has a 64-bit install, so that's why you can't configure anything (you need the "SQL Server Network Configuration", not the "SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration" -- but then the 64-bit version of that). I'm not sure how you get to that interesting situation, maybe something with messed-up shortcuts. Try starting `%windir%\system32\SQLServerManager13.msc` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks sooo much, had no idea it was a 32bit installation until you mentioned. Plus now SQL Server Network Configuration ( as you rightfully pointed) out has a full set of properties.

Comment: Let me dive in and check if updates work to the port number etc